# Config ServletRegistrationBean in @SpringBootApplication main class, test with mockmvc response 404

Tags: mockmvc, spring-boot-test

spring boot version is 2.0.0.RELEASE.

test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={Application.class},webEnvironment=SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class ProcControllerTest {

@Autowired
private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Test
public void testGetProc() throws Exception {
    String requestUrl = "/app/rest/query/proc";
    // Request json body
    JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
    jsonBody.put("id", "101");
    String contentBody = jsonBody.toJSONString();

    MvcResult mvcResult = mockMvc.perform(post(requestUrl)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .content(contentBody)
    ).andReturn();

    MockHttpServletResponse response = mvcResult.getResponse();
    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);


}
```

}

I alse tried another test config :

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class},
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
//@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
public class ProcessInstanceControllerMockMvcTest {

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();
}
```

Application.class is below：

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ApplicationConfiguration.class})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
builder) {
    return builder.sources(Application.class);
}


@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean apiDispatcher(){
    DispatcherServlet api = new DispatcherServlet();
    api.setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
    api.setContextConfigLocation(ApiDispatcherServletConfiguration.class.getName());
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setServlet(api);
    registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/api/*");
    registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
    registrationBean.setName("api");
    return registrationBean;
}


@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean appDispatcher(){
    DispatcherServlet app = new DispatcherServlet();
    app.setContextClass(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.class);
    app.setContextConfigLocation(AppDispatcherServletConfiguration.class.getName());
    ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean();
    registrationBean.setServlet(app);
    registrationBean.addUrlMappings("/app/*");
    registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
    registrationBean.setName("app");
    return registrationBean;
}
```

}

The test run simple log is below :

> 10:58:26.015[main][INFO ]Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].log:180
>       10:58:26.015[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet '': initialization started  o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet.initServletBean:494
>       10:58:26.699[main][INFO ]Mapped ...... Multi line
>       10:58:30.408[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 4392 ms  o.s.t.w.s.TestDispatcherServlet.initServletBean:513
>       10:58:31.159[main][INFO ]SpringTemplateLoader for FreeMarker: using resource loader[org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55: startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:57:51 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy] and template loader path [classpath:/templates/]  o.s.u.f.SpringTemplateLoader.:62
>       10:58:31.163[main][INFO ]ClassTemplateLoader for Spring macros added to FreeMarker configuration  o.s.w.s.v.f.FreeMarkerConfigurer.postProcessTemplateLoaders:131
>       10:58:33.065[main][INFO ]Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-auto-1"]  o.a.c.h.Http11NioProtocol.log:180
>       10:58:33.082[main][INFO ]Using a shared selector for servlet write/read  o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool.log:180
>       10:58:33.114[main][INFO ]Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'app'  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].log:180
>       10:58:33.115[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet 'app': initialization started  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean:494
>       10:58:33.121[main][INFO ]Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'app-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:58:33 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh:589
>       10:58:33.123[main][INFO ]Successfully resolved class for [com.fg.app.servlet.AppDispatcherServletConfiguration]  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions:233
>       10:58:34.034[main][INFO ]JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.:154
>       10:58:26.699[main][INFO ]Mapped ...... Multi line
>       10:58:35.186[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet 'app': initialization completed in 2071 ms  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean:513
>       10:58:35.199[main][INFO ]Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'api'  o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].log:180
>       10:58:35.200[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet 'api': initialization started  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean:494
>       10:58:35.201[main][INFO ]Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'api-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:58:35 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh:589
>       10:58:35.202[main][INFO ]Successfully resolved class for [com.fg.app.servlet.ApiDispatcherServletConfiguration]  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions:233
>       10:58:35.661[main][INFO ]JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring  o.s.b.f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.:154
>       10:58:26.699[main][INFO ]Mapped ...... Multi line
>       10:58:36.303[main][INFO ]FrameworkServlet 'api': initialization completed in 1103 ms  o.s.w.s.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean:513
>       10:58:36.305[main][INFO ]Tomcat started on port(s): 53711 (http) with context path ''  o.s.b.w.e.t.TomcatWebServer.start:205
>       10:58:36.309[main][INFO ]Started ProcControllerTest in 46.914 seconds (JVM running for 51.157)  c.f.a.ProcControllerTest.logStarted:59
>       10:58:37.160[Thread-9][INFO ]Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55: startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:57:51 CST 2018]; root of context hierarchy  o.s.b.w.s.c.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext.doClose:989
>       10:58:37.180[Thread-9][INFO ]Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'  o.s.o.j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.destroy:572
>       10:58:37.196[Thread-9][INFO ]{dataSource-1} closed  c.a.d.p.DruidDataSource.close:1823
>       10:58:37.360[localhost-startStop-2][INFO ]Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'app-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:58:33 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose:989
>       10:58:37.364[localhost-startStop-2][INFO ]Closing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'api-servlet': startup date [Wed Jul 04 10:58:35 CST 2018]; parent: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@61f80d55  o.s.w.c.s.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.doClose:989

Test Result :org.junit.ComparisonFailure: Expected :200 Actual   :404

Through the above log, I guess the class `TestDispatcherServlet` is the reason. when I use `TestRestTemplate`, it does not init `TestDispatcherServlet`, and works fun.

Answer (score 0):

`MockMvc` uses a `DispatcherServlet` different from the one registered by the app.  The URLs you pass to it should be the exact same URLs you specified in your `@Controller` annotations.